# How to call a script with flags and get it's global vars?

Tags: perl

I'm looking for something like this `require "peacefullscript.pl -whiteflag";` the problem that this one doesn't work. What I want is to call a script with some flags and get the global variables it creates into the current script.

How can I do this **easily**?

Comment: Did you mean that you need the variables which are set by the `flags` you pass to the script `peacefullscript.pl` as commandline argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@ARGV = ("-whiteflag");
require "peacefullscript.pl";
```

Comment: The solution using `local` is better. For the reasons given in that answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
{
    local @ARGV = ("-whiteflag");
    do "peacefullscript.pl";
}
```

The `local` keyword creates a temporary copy of `@ARGV` that won't overwrite your original command line arguments.